# Is Lwc @api property still read-only as of 2021?

Tags: lightning-web-components

@api property used to be read-only for the component that hosts it, but it's not the case today, we are able to assign values to api property.

Is this a bug?

Eg: Child comp:

```
@api apiProp

ConnectedCallback() {
   apiProp = "test"; // this line used to give error. But now it's not.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The LWC framework **doesn't do anything to prevent public property reassignment**. In other words, from within your component, you are allowed to set the value of properties marked with the `@api` decorator.

In general, it is a bad practice to override a public property from within a component as it goes against the unidirectional dataflow model. There are still valid use cases for component to reflect their internal component state change via a public property. A good example of this is a custom input component reflecting its internal value change to the `value` public property.

The [`@lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments`](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-api-reassignments.md#prevent-public-property-reassignments-no-api-reassignments) ESLint can help catching those issues. This rule is enabled by default with the [`@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc/recommended`](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-config-lwc#salesforceeslint-config-lwcrecommended-configuration) ESLint config.

---

That said, the LWC framework **prevents mutation to objects passed as public property**. If a component receives an object via public property, any property addition, update or delete on the object will result in an `Invalid mutation` error.

Note that this check is only enforced in dev/debug mode to avoid the performance overhead in production.

---

The following example showcases the difference between public property reassignment and object mutation.

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class extends LightningElement {
    @api aString;
    @api anObject;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.aString = 'test'   //  Valid
        this.anObject.test = 1  //  Invalid mutation: Cannot set "test" on "[object Object]". "[object Object]" is read-only.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation now makes no mention of restrictions on writing to @api properties, and also states:

> Note
>
> Reactivity changed significantly in the Lightning Web Components Open Source 1.1.0 release.

As far as I can tell, this is perfectly legal. I even wrote some code that compiles and runs according to this [new behavior](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2GfaGh8MR9XYvWgrCGT9/src/app.js).

However, be aware that if the parent changes the value, it will be overridden.

I think this change was implemented to allow you to set a default value when you call a @wire or other asynchronous code, but still need to set a default value for the component.

To be certain, though, I'll doublecheck with some people. In the meantime, I don't recommend doing this if another option is available. Data should always flow from parent to child, so if you do this, you are potentially breaking assumptions.